# Return only matched occurrences with strstr()

Tags: php

Say I have the following string:

> $string = 'Great @jason I think @sally would love it too.'

I'm using:

```
$mentions = strstr($string, '@');
echo $mentions
```

**Which outputs**

```
@jason I think @sally would love it too.
```

**Desired output**

```
@jason @sally
```

I just can't figure how to do this in php, in js I simply do:

```
hashtags = /\@\w+/g;
var matches = string.match(hashtags);
alert(matches);
```

preg_match() in php returns a boolean, so the closest I can get is with strstr()... but returns the whole string after the first match.

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual about `preg_match` instead of guessing what it does?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It's a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` with that same regex:

```
<?php

$string = 'Great @jason I think @sally would love it too.';
preg_match_all("/@\w+/", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

?>
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/NgrRvH**

Comment: If everyone is down-voting. Maybe be so kind to leave a message why? This answer seems fully valid.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, and yeah next time I'll try reading the resources better

Comment: @Allendar Well, sometimes the downvotes are for punishment for answering a question that could be solved easily by searching in the docs or on SO. The downvoter may think "you're answering for -easy- reps !". It's kinda sad to punish someone who wants to help ...

Comment: @Blender is there a way to translate the array into a string e.i:jason, sally. As I'm inserting to a db.

Comment: @Aaron: I'd ask a separate question. I don't use PHP enough to give you anything useful when it comes to database access.